# Top 5 values from vertical list in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have an excel file with one column corresponding to each player's name and the another row corresponding to the number of shots per player. See following example:

[image]

In excel, I need to figure out how to list the top 5 players based on number of shots, using an excel forumula. So, I would like for the query to return a 5 x 1 column vector in excel. What cell formula could I use to achieve this? End result should be the following:

[image]

Also, given that their will be repeating values and blank values, its needs to handle such.

Comment: you need an array formula to read the scores, and use the large function to return the 1st largest, 2nd largest etc...

Comment: Why is player4 in top5 instead of player2 or even player7?? Why is player 11 and 8 both in the top5 but player 2 and 7 aren't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the data setup as you have it, and 'Player 1' in `B1`, use this array formula for the first of the top5 (I used cell A6 for my first entry):

`=INDEX($B$1:$L$1,MATCH(LARGE($B$2:$L$2-COLUMN($B$2:$L$2)/100000000,ROWS($A$6:$A6)),$B$2:$L$2-COLUMN($B$2:$L$2)/100000000, 0))`

Enter the formula with

> Ctrl-Shift-Enter

and then copy down....

Note that the tie-break is going from left to right, so the answer is :

Player 8

Player 11

Player 9

Player 2

Player 4